# Can a set containing a single vector from a vector space over a finite field be linearly dependent?

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields

Take the set $S=\{v=(1,1)\}\subset F_2 ^2$. $v+v=(0,0)$ is a linear combination of vectors from $S$. Is $S$ linearly dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $S$ is linearly independent. We, indeed, have $v+v=(0,0)$, but given that here $-v=v$ that does not say any more about linear (in)dependence than the equation $v-v=(0,0)$ would in a vector space over reals.

Yet another way of saying the same thing is to observe that 
$$
v+v=1\cdot v+1\cdot v=(1+1)\cdot v =0\cdot v,
$$
so the l.h.s. of $v+v=(0,0)$ **is** the trivial linear combination, where all the scalars are equal to zero.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. The question arose from a problem involving finding a minimal set of linearly dependent vectors, so I'm a little sad the answer is no.

Comment: @crf ${(0,0)}$ is linearly dependent, since $1 \times v = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to see the answer is: Suppose r*(1,1) = (0,0). Since r is a scalar in F(2), it can only be 0 or 1. If r = 0, then S is linearly independent. If r = 1, then 1*(1,1) = (1,1) not equal to (0,0). So S is independent.